# Flatulence while listening to a Jewish song

Tags: halacha, torah-study, music, health-safety-shmira, smell

In [Hilchot Kri'at Shema 3:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Reading_the_Shema.3.14), Maimonides writes:

> If one is reciting [the Shema] and passes gas, he should stop until the odor subsides and resume his recitation afterwards. The same applies to one studying Torah.
>
> When another person passes gas, even though one should stop reciting the Shema, he need not interrupt his Torah study.

Let's say you're listening to some Jewish music on Spotify, and the lyrics are from Tanach. Unexpectely, you release a sudden fart. Should you pause the song until the air clears? Why or why not?

Comment: I guess it depends if you view listening to verses of Tanakh as a genuine religious experience or if you think our holy scriptures are just nice background noise.

Comment: @DoubleAA is one allowed to use pesukim as nice backround music, ie. working out to it?

Comment: @Nafkamina See the question: ["Can songs use the words from pesukim?"](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48900/can-songs-use-the-words-from-pesukim)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to.

Furthermore, according to some poskim, you could even listen to the song in the shower. See [this Q/A set by dinonline.org](http://www.dinonline.org/2011/04/13/music-in-shower/):

> **The Question:**
>   Is one allowed to listen to Jewish music while showering
>   in the bathroom?
>
> **Answer:**
>   Yes, I don’t see any problem in this. The music does not have
>   the halachah of spoken pesukim, and even if they do there is no
>   prohibition of listening to pesukim while showering. However, you
>   should not sing along with pesukim, for one may not speak divrei torah
>   in the shower.

According this reasoning, since it is not considered as if you are speaking the words, it would seem to be permissible even if there is a flatulent smell. Thus, you would not need to pause the music.

Comment: +0. Thank you for replying. But what is your source (or your reasoning) for saying that I don't need to pause the song?

Comment: @unforgettableid im pretty i explained my reasoning in the answer above : "According this reasoning, since it is not considered as if you are speaking the words, it would seem to be permissible even if there is a flatulent smell. Thus, you would not need to pause the music."