# Ring With Part of Pasuk Engraved on it

Tags: halacha, bathroom

I have a silver ring with the words "Gam Ki Elech Lo Ira Ra Ki Ata Imadi" engraved into it. It is the same font as words in a torah. 
The words are meant to be written as a play on words from psalm 23 and are now referring to a spouse. Two of the words have letter that connect to an adjacent word (some suggested that may invalidate them as halchik "words" in order to avoid any issues).

Is it ok to wear this ring in the bathroom? Or handle impure items while wearing it?

Comment: Is it on the inside or outside of the ring?

Comment: it is on the outside. on the inside there are initials in Hebrew and the date in Hebrew.

Answer (score 1):

As always, CYLOR especially as this doesn't seem to be an open-and-shut question. See [this](http://www.mevaseret.org/mmy/journal/5772/137-172-Rabbi%20Eli%20Ozarowski.pdf) thorough article where they discuss your question.

> The Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh Deah 283:4) codifies the Rambam as well, ruling
>   that it is indeed forbidden to embroider pesukim into a tallit, and
>   the Beit Yosef, written by Rav Yosef Karo himself, makes mention of both
>   of these reasons offered by the Rambam. Based on this case, it would
>   appear that even if one would argue that the first reason above is not
>   sufficient to absolutely forbid our case of using pesukim in jewelry or
>   other clothing, it would still be prohibited to make, and most probably
>   buy, such an object based on the second reason. Even if a person
>   attempts to be careful not to bring it into unclean areas, it is very
>   difficult to assure that it is never taken to the bathroom.

Nonetheless, there *might* be room for leniency based on one side of a difference of opinion quoted in the aforementioned article

> Rav Yaakov Ariel (B’oholah shel Torah siman 42) argues that perhaps
>   there is room to be lenient that not only may one wear jewelry or rings
>   (or sweat shirts) with Torah verses on it, it may even be permitted
>   to bring them into the bathroom, since perhaps the verses are intended
>   not as Torah content, but rather simply as an expression of friendship.
>   For example, the phrase of “Ani L’dodi V’dodi Li,” “Iam to my beloved
>   as my beloved is to me,”found on a ring may not have been intended to
>   refer specifically to the verse in Shir HaShirim(6:3),but rather is
>   simply being used as a “catch phrase”to demonstrate a person’s
>   affection or friendship for another individual.

Comment: [Thy children have made me as a harp upon which they frivolously play](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48910/759)

Comment: Note in the OP's case it was written in Ktav Ashuri so it's hard to say the use of the verse as a verse wasn't intentional.

Comment: "mention of both of these reasons offered by the Rambam" what are those reasons and which apply to this case? It's not clear in your post