# How can verses from the Torah be written on paper without the paper becoming sheimos?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, shemos-sacred-names

I often find myself mindlessly doodling psukim from Tanach on paper (especially Tehillim). Is there any way I can do this without making the paper sheimos?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't be "mindlessly doodling psukim". They're not verses to be written on a page and then discarded, mindlessly.

Answer (score 2):

As Ezra already commented `you shouldn't be "mindlessly doodling psukim"`.

See the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 23:13 -  [סימן כח - הלכות ספר תורה ושאר ספרי קדש](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0027_L2) - who says that it's forbidden to write a verse without first lining the paper.

> **סעיף יג'**: 
>   **אָסוּר לִכְתֹּב פָּסוּק בְּלִי שִׂרְטוּט** (עַיֵּן מָגֵן אַבְרָהָם סִימָן ל"ב סָעִיף קָטֹן ז')‏

All the more so it should be forbidden to doodle disregarding any lines that may be there.

As you can see from the [Mishna Berura 32:20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.32.6?lang=bi&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.32.20&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) that the problem is not only writing an entire verse, but even writing 3 words from a verse without adhering to the lines is fobidden.

> **כ**) **שיטה עליונה** - משום דתפילין אין עליה הלמ"מ לשרטט כמו מזוזה רק משום **דאסור לכתוב ג' תיבות מפסוק בלי שרטוט**‏

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48910/759 All the more so you can't mindlessly doodle them.