# Can't find this song

Tags: music, shir-hashirim

I can't seem to find this song that I once heard. It was based on [Shir Hashirim 7:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Song_of_Songs.7.1?lang=bi).

The lyrics were:

שׁ֤וּבִי שׁ֙וּבִי֙ הַשּׁ֣וּלַמִּ֔ית שׁ֥וּבִי שׁ֖וּבִי וְנֶחֱזֶה־בָּ֑ךְ מַֽה־תֶּחֱזוּ֙ בַּשּׁ֣וּלַמִּ֔ית כִּמְחֹלַ֖ת הַֽמַּחֲנָֽיִם"

I coulda sworn it was Yehuda Green but I can't seem to find it.

Anyone know?

Comment: Was it on [Sanhedrin 101a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48910/759)?

Comment: Yehoshua Engelman?

Comment: Is this question [on topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here?

Answer (score 4):

Don't really know if this question is on-topic, but I've also been looking for this song for a few years. Tried a different route when I saw the question and happily, I found it. It's called Niggun Moshe and can be heard [here](https://youtube.com/watch?v=FY_Q0QtTTyg).

According to [this post](https://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2979490&whichpage=#R_4), it was originally a niggun composed by R' Moshe Shor and named after him.

Comment: Yes!!!!! Great song!