# Hosea 2:21 וְאֵרַשְׂתִּ֥יךְ לִ֖י לְעוֹלָ֑ם

Tags: halacha

I recall learning once that it is impermissible to use וְאֵרַשְׂתִּ֥יךְ לִ֖י לְעוֹלָ֑ם ([Hosea 2:21-22](https://www.sefaria.org/Hosea.2.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) to refer to husband-wife (or even to use on a wedding invitation).

I would appreciate being directed to the source.  Thanks-

Jeff

Comment: That's interesting where did you hear this? A number of commentaries point to the fact that the relationship between the Jewish people and G-d is represented through this imagery of an engaged couple. Unless of course, the thinking is that we should not make our relationship with Hashem humanistic

Comment: @Dov that's one angle. Another (related) angle is those words are reserved for Hashem and His people

Comment: It's probably from this widely ignored Talmudic story https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48910/759