Can you sing religious songs in the restroom?
Is it allowed to sing in the restroom? I understand some customs hold that you shouldn't speak in the restroom, but what if someone enjoyed singing in the shower? Also, what if someone sang religious songs in the shower? Would you need to replace any words?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48910/759

Ben Ish Hai, year 1. In a restroom, you’re not even allowed to THINK of concepts RELATED to Torah, or even some words related to Jewish subjects.

According to the Yabia Omer:

Regarding a room that houses a bathtub or shower nowadays, one may not
recite any words of holiness in it. One is permitted, however, to
think words of Torah in it and may therefore listen to a Torah lecture
or holy songs from the radio and the like there.
Note: Obviously, the aforementioned Halacha applies only to a room
that houses a bathtub or shower alone; however, if there is a toilet
in the room, one may not even think words of Torah there.



According to Shulchan Aruch OC 85:2, one is allowed to speak (or sing, what's the difference?) secular matters in a bathroom.

According Shulchan Aruch HaRav there, one should ideally (and probably halachically) not hum any melodies from Jewish songs (religious) in the bathroom, even without lyrics.



That link doesn't appear to go to the Shulchan Aruch HaRav. Can you clarify what authority you are citing and what they say?

@DoubleAA will do in a few hours, or tomorrow. Have a good day/evening
